# How can I center the Google sign in button in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I'm having some trouble centering the Google sign in button horizontally and vertically in React. I've tried all the normal solutions for centering stuff, but none of it has any effect.

```
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId={clientId}
            buttonText={loading}
            onSuccess={handleLoginSuccess}
            onFailure={handleLoginFailure}
            onRequest={handleRequest}
            onAutoLoadFinished={handleAutoLoadFinished}
            isSignedIn={true}
          />}
```

There's the component I'm using for the button. I haven't done any custom styling to it. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making an empty div
center it
and put "GoogleLogin" in it without any style

Comment: strangely it throws a syntax error when i do this
edit: never mind, i'm trying this now